# RavenDB range querying documents by number field

Tags: ravendb

I want to filter my documents in database through RavenDB Studio using range search in simple query by numeric field.

```
MyNumericCount:[100 TO 200]
```

Instead of correct result I receive set of documents with various values of my field.

Why does it happen? How to properly query RavenDB.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are querying on a numeric field, but you are looking at the textual representation.

You need to query using:

```
MyNumericCount_Range:[Ix100 TO Ix200]
```

The Ix prefix is for ints, Dx for double, Lx for longs, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to do this way but with such approach the result is empty. Should I use this syntax with custom index or it should work with dynamic one?